# INDEX MATCH with 2 criteria, match with partial text

Tags: excel, formula

My data looks like this:

```
C.............F.............. H

Jane......Blue..........NON

Bob........Blue..........OUI

Jack.......Red..........OUI

Sarah.....Blue..........OUI

John ......Blue.........NON

Claude......Blue.........(empty)
```

This formula is gonna look in column C if the person has BLUE and OUI.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$9:$C$514;MATCH(1;("BLUE"=$F$9:$F$514)*("OUI"=$H$9:$H$514);0));"AUCUN")`

Output `Bob`

Then, I have this for the second match
`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$9:$C$514;SMALL(IF($H$9:$H$514="OUI";IF($F$9:$F$514="BLUE";ROW($F$9:$F$514)-ROW(INDEX($F$9:$F$514;1;1))+1));2));"AUCUN")`

Output `Sarah`

However, I would want the field "OUI" to be a partial text match. So whenever it finds the letter "O", it would return a match.

So the first match would be `Jane`, the second match would be `Bob`. I tried replacing `"OUI"` by `"*O*"` but it tells me that nothing was found.

Comment: Can you share what your output looks like given your data to make sure there is no confusion?

Comment: Edited my post. Instead of `Bob` as a 1st match and `Sarah` as a 2nd match, I would want it to be `Jane` and `Bob`

Answer (score 2):

If one has the Dynamic Array formula FILTER:

```
=FILTER(C2:C6,(F2:F6="BLUE")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("O",H2:H6))))
```

[image]

---

If not then use INDEX(AGGREGATE())

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($F$2:$F$6)/(($F$2:$F$6="BLUE")*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("O",$H$2:$H$6)))),ROW($ZZ1))),"AUCUN")
```

[image]

Comment: In your experience, which of the new Dynamic array formulas have you been using the most? FILTER seems like a big candidate.

Comment: @BigBen by far FILTER() with UNIQUE() a close second.  I have found a lot of uses for the others, also.